# How do I get the background color from typescript file in angular and bind it to my html page?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have an array that is being populated in typescript and based on the value in the array, I want to set a different background color for my div but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried to set the background using [style.backgroundColor]="statusColor[i]". statusColor is an array declared in my typescript. It works normally if I try to bind it without an array to a single object as below:
[style.backgroundColor]="statusColor". This is the error I'm getting:
Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Here is the code:
This is my interface for the json object:

```
export interface IComplaint {
    id: string;
    description: string
    status: string
}
```

This is the typescript for my main component:

```
public complaints = {} as IComplaint[];        
public statusColor: string[];
```

After the complaints are populated in the array I use this function to set the color:

```
for (let i=0; i<this.complaints.length; i++) {
        if (this.complaints[i].status === "Reported")
          this.statusColor[i] = 'red';
        else if (this.complaints[i].status === "Resolved")
          this.statusColor[i] = 'green';
        else if (this.complaints[i].status === "In progress")
          this.statusColor[i] = 'yellow';
        console.log(this.statusColor[i]);
    }
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<mat-card class="card" *ngFor="let complaint of complaints; let i = index">
<div class="status" [style.backgroundColor]="statusColor[i]">
                        {{ complaint.status }}
                </div>
</mat-card>

<div class="status" [style.backgroundColor]="statusColor[i]">
                            {{ complaint.status }}
                    </div>
```

I want the background color to change based on the status.

Comment: Ummm... Not related to your issue, but `{} as IComplaint[]`? How about just `complaints: IComplaint[] = []`?

Comment: Also forgot a semicolon in this statement: `let complaint of complaints let i = index`

Comment: And, if memory serves: `[style.backgroundColor="statusColor[i]"]` should be `[style.backgroundColor]="statusColor[i]"`

Comment: Also, `var i in this.complaints` is not the correct way to iterate an array.

Comment: Yeah that would work as well but I'm able to load the JSON objects into the complaints array just fine this way as well.

Comment: I've made the changes and it still doesn't work. This is the error I'm getting: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Your `statusColor` property is not initialized.

Answer (score 6):

Try ngStyle as follows

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': statusColor[i]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the style binding should be: 
`[style.background-color]="statusColor[i]"`

If you want to improve your code, I would suggest you to use a pipe to do the processing.
Pipe is really performance friendly too.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'complaintBgColourPipe'
})
export class ComplaintBgColourPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    switch (value) {
      case 'Reported': {
        return 'red';
      }

      case 'Resolved': {
        return 'green';
      }

      case 'In progress': {
        return 'yellow';
      }

      default: {
        return '';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Since you're going loop through all your complaints array, you can just pass the status in and pipe it.