# How to set background color of a div in angular?

Tags: angular

I have an angular web app where my html is as follows:

```
<p class="news-source" style="background-color: {{news.backgroundColor}}">{{news.source.title}}</p>
```

My component has the following :

```
this.news = new News()
this.news.backgroundColor = '#E6E6CA'
```

However, I see that the color does not get set if I use {{news.backgroundColor}}. What is the correct way to set the background color?

```
style="background-color: #E6E6CA"
```

This works if  I use the hex directly. But, I want to use news.backgroundColor to set the color. So, wondering what is the correct usage.

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I get the background color from typescript file in angular and bind it to my html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432890/how-do-i-get-the-background-color-from-typescript-file-in-angular-and-bind-it-to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to surround `style` with `[]` otherwise, it's just going to be interpreted as a string. Do it like this:

```html
<p class="news-source" [style.backgroundColor]="news.backgroundColor">{{news.source.title}}</p>
```

You could also define an object in your component, instead of setting each property individually:

```js
public myStyle = {
  "background-color": this.news.backgroundColor
}
```

```html
<p class="news-source" [style]="myStyle">{{news.source.title}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

as long as news.backgroundcolor is a public member, your approach works fine.
ts:

```
export class myClass {
news = {"backgroundcolor":"#e6e6ca"}
}
```

html:

```
<p style="background-color:{{news.backgroundcolor}};">
```

[See the example:](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-niqngd)

If the property / member is private or the scope otherwise inaccessible (null) it obviously won't work.

Also, You should generally be using classes IMO.